# In hyperledger composer acl file, what is the difference between resource defination syntax?

Tags: acl, blockchain, hyperledger

In acl file I have seen resource definition in following three syntaxes

1. org.hyperledger.composer.system.*
2. org.hyperledger.composer.system.**
3. **

what is the difference between these three and if there are any other possible definitions please do explain those thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From reference: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language

"Resource defines the things that the ACL rule applies to. This can be a class, all classes within a namespace, or all classes under a namespace. It can also be an instance of a class."

### Resource Examples:

1. Namespace: `org.example.*`

   - Includes: `org.example.ResrourceA` and `org.example.ResourceB`
2. Namespace (recursive): `org.example.**`

   - Includes: `org.example.namespace1.*` and `org.example.namespace2.*`
3. Class in namespace: `org.example.Car`
4. Instance of a class: `org.example.Car#ABC123`